# Can I import a VS2005 Solution for C++ App into an IDE for debugging it on Linux?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unix, visual-studio-debugging

Can I import a VS2005 Solution for C++ app into some IDE that runs on Linux and allows me to debug the app? It is a working app and already has a makefile for Linux.

Comment: A Linux IDE is more likely to be able to import a Linux project complete with Makefiles than something called "solution". But you don't need an IDE to debug a program. You need `gdb`. If you need a GUI for it, try `ddd` (a bit dated but still works well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codelite allows you to import Visual Studio projects
http://www.codelite.org/

However, it also allows you to import Makefile based projects, and you will probably get more mileage using this method.  You can then use the codelite IDE to debug your application.  It is just a wrapper around the GDB debugger.

Although using codelite to debug your application will be more user friendly, I recommend learning GDB as there may be situations where you need to debug something and an IDE is not available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an IDE on Linux, to perform the debugging with, you can use Eclipse, Kproject, etc, but you will have to create a project and then import your code manually to get it to work. It might be more work than its worth, so you might be just as well served with n.m.'s comment to your question in using gdb and ddd.